# How could several instances UnknownFormat error in controller suddenly appear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My app's view specs started failing because of a change we introduced to version control and I'm trying to debug.

Essentially, we had a ton of view specs that always passed, and now many, but not all, of them produce `ActionController::UnknownFormat` errors in the controller.  Here is an example of a method that is blowing up:

```
  def show
    @user = current_user
    FooCountItem.increment_requests
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @foo }
    end
  end
```

Here's an example of spec that just began to fail:

```
describe "show.html.erb", type: :feature do

  context "as admin" do

    let!(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }
    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

    before :each do
      page.set_rack_session(user_id: user.id)
      visit data_service_path(foo.id)
    end


    it "displays the foo's name" do
      expect(page).to have_content(foo.name)
    end
  end
end
```

How is it possible that html is not the expected response?  How could the controller react as if it has to produce a different format?

Thanks.

**Updated**:  I'm also seeing `NoMethodError: undefined method 'symbolize_keys' for "":String` on some lines that are doing the controller requests from the controller_specs.  I have no changes in spec_helper.rb when compared to working version of the test suite.

If I add `format: :html` to a call in the controller spec, it passes.  I must have the app globally configured to respond to :js.

Comment: So can you tell us what was the change that caused this? (try git bisect if you're not sure)

Comment: None of the code you've shown explains the problem you're seeing, either show more code or better still, show the change that triggered the problem.